# How can I insert a line with `:normal!`?

Tags: normal-mode

`:normal! )i<CR>` will go to the start of the next sentence and insert the actual characters `<CR>`.

How can I modify this to insert a line break instead?

(I've also tried `\n` and `\r` instead of `<CR>`, and escaping them like `\\r`, but in every case, what's inserted is the characters themselves.)

Comment: Instead of typing `<`, `C`, `R`, `>`, press `<C-v>` then `<return>` to insert a literal `^M`.

Comment: Other way to do is with 'o'. :normal! )o. It automatically start inserting at next line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand `<cr>` as a newline, you need to use commands which evaluate it as an expression. In this case, you need [`execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute):

```
:exe 'normal!' ")i\<cr>"
```

Or, as romainl says, you enter a literal newline using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Note the `\` before `<cr>`. From [`:h string`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#string):

```
string                                  string String expr-string E114
------
"string"                string constant         expr-quote

Note that double quotes are used.

A string constant accepts these special characters:
\...    three-digit octal number (e.g., "\316")
…
\n      newline <NL>
\r      return <CR>
…
\<xxx>  Special key named "xxx".  e.g. "\<C-W>" for CTRL-W.  This is for use
        in mappings, the 0x80 byte is escaped.  Don't use <Char-xxxx> to get a
        utf-8 character, use \uxxxx as mentioned above.
```

So, with `:exe`, you can also use `\r`:

```
:exe 'normal!' ")i\r"
```

Comment: Nice, does that mean we can escape arbitrary key with execute?

Comment: @nobe4 Only those listed in [`:h keycodes`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#keycodes), I think (which is a lot of keys, but not all of them)